# Using Spike finder in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon, point, topology

I tried to modify spikeRemover from Schmidt & Krüger. My goal it's to obtain, for each polygon, the position of the spikes. I don't need to remove it. 
For some reason, that I can't figure out, my script fails and I don't obtain any position.
Probably there is a problem at the union of different points but I don't know how to manage it in another way.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_SpikeFinder (geometry, angle double precision)
     returns geometry as 
     $body$
     DECLARE
     ingeom alias for $1;
     angle  alias for $2;
     lineusp geometry;
     newgeom geometry;
     numpoints integer;
     point_id integer;
     result_pnt geometry;


    begin
            -- input geometry or rather set as default for the output 
        newgeom := ingeom;

        -- check polygon
        if (select st_geometrytype(ingeom)) = 'ST_Polygon' then
            if (select st_numinteriorrings(ingeom)) = 0 then

            lineusp := st_boundary(ingeom) as line;
                    numpoints := st_numpoints(lineusp);
            point_id := 0;


                -- the geometry passes pointwisely
            while (point_id <= numpoints) loop
                        result_pnt := ST_Collect(result_pnt, st_pointn(lineusp, point_id));
                    -- the check of the angle at the current point of a spike including the special case, that it is the first point.
                    if (select abs(pi() - abs(st_azimuth(st_pointn(lineusp, case when point_id= 1 then st_numpoints(lineusp) - 1 else point_id - 1 end), 
                                st_pointn(lineusp, point_id)) - st_azimuth(st_pointn(lineusp, point_id), st_pointn(lineusp, point_id + 1))))) <= angle then

        (probably the problem is here)      --->        result_pnt := ST_Union(result_pnt, st_pointn(lineusp, point_id));

end if;
            point_id = point_id + 1;
            end loop;
        end if;
        end if;
            return result_pnt;
     end;
     $body$
       language 'plpgsql' volatile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the position where use ST_union. 
The correct way is to use an array of geometry to collect all points and then, before the restitution command , create a geometry of multipoint made by ST_collect.

result_pnt geometry[];
 ...

result_pnt[point_id] := st_pointn(lineusp, point_id);
 ...

return ST_Collect(result_pnt);

Comment: Can you post the corrected function as well...thanks